# How to remove leading zero from %m for x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I remove leading zeros from the x axis labels WITHOUT MANUALLY adding custom labels?

```
   p + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m/%d", #this generated dates like: 02/15, 03/15, etc
                 date_breaks = "1 week",
                 expand = expand_scale(0,0))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a simple change to your `strftime` format string. However, it depends on your platform (Unix or Windows).

#### Windows

Insert a pound sign (`#`) before the `m`:

```r
p + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%#m/%d", #this generated dates like: 2/15, 3/15, etc
                 date_breaks = "1 week",
                 expand = expand_scale(0,0))
```

#### Unix

Insert a minus sign (`-`) before the `m`:

```r
p + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%-m/%d", #this generated dates like: 2/15, 3/15, etc
                 date_breaks = "1 week",
                 expand = expand_scale(0,0))
```

Comment: What do you see when you run this? Note that it won't remove leading zeros from the day, only the month. To remove the zeros from the day, add a minus in front of the `d` as well.

Comment: @RyanFrost I just get e.g. `[1] "-m/01"` when I try this.

Comment: Ah OK, I think it was an issue with Windows vs Linux. See the updated answer

Comment: yep, that was it!

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
p + scale_x_date(labels = function(z) gsub("^0", "", strftime(z, "%m/%d")),
                 date_breaks = "1 week",
                 expand = expand_scale(0, 0))
```

As shown in the following reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-05-30"), 
                                       as.Date("2020-07-18"), length.out = 50),
                       value = sample(50)), aes(date, value)) + geom_col()
p
```

[image]

```r
p + scale_x_date(labels = function(z) gsub("^0", "", strftime(z, "%m/%d")),
                 date_breaks = "1 week",
                 expand = expand_scale(0, 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I got this: `Error in format(x, format, tz = tz) : unused arguments (format, tz = tz)`

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian see my update. It should have been `labels = ` instead of `date_labels = `

Comment: yep, that was it!